# Constructing a compact real form of $\mathbb G_m$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected, reductive group over $\mathbb C$.  General theory of reductive groups tells us that $G$ has a unique anisotropic real form, i.e. a connected reductive group $G_0$ over $\mathbb R$ such that $G_0(\mathbb R)$ is compact and $G_0 \times_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C = G$ as complex algebraic groups.  Then $G_0(\mathbb R)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $G(\mathbb C)$.

Consider the special case $G = \mathbb G_m$.  Then $G(\mathbb C) = \mathbb C^{\ast}$, which has maximal compact subgroup $S^1$. I want to find a group $G_0$ over $\mathbb R$ such that $G_0(\mathbb R) = S^1$ and $G_0 \times_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C = G$.

I could try to take the group $G_0 \subset \mathbb A_{\mathbb R}^2$ defined on points by $x^2 +y^2 = 1$.  But I don't think $G_0 \times_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb G_m$.

How should one go about constructing $G_0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have constructed $G_0$: $\Bbb R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1)\otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C = \Bbb C[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1)$, and under the change of variables $u=-x-iy,v=x-iy$ we have that $\Bbb C[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1) \cong \Bbb C[u,v]/(uv-1)$, which is of course isomorphic to $\Bbb G_m$ over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Oh..$\space \space$